# Windows Phone Emulator not working

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

When I try to start debugging my windows phone 8 app in `Emulator WVGA 512MB` the following error message is showing

```
The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to connect to the Windows Phone operating system:

The emulator couldn't determine the host IP address, which is used to communicate with the guest virtual machine.

Some functionality may be disabled.
```

and the emulator is always showing `The Windows Phone OS is starting...` 
Can't understand what's the problem. Please advice.

Comment: try to open the Hyper V manager and then delete the installed virtual machine. Now go back to visual Studio and Try running the application again. This installs a new version of emulator on Hyper V. Check it. That might solve the problem

Comment: I eventually gave up and tried different variants (720p, WVGA etc.) until one of them worked (`10.0.10586.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB` FWIW)

Comment: There are so many emulators and the one you mentioned is the only one that may work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At last the problem is solved.

1. Open Hyper V Manager
2. Delete all installed Virtual Machines
3. Delete all Virtual Switches
4. Restart system
5. Rerun visual studio

Thanks to [Shiv Kumar Ganesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519305/shiv-kumar-ganesh)

Comment: this worked for me ... one thing though, if you cannot delete virtual switches then remove them from registry and restart the system See this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e49df568-4f4c-47b7-b30c-952d1e26ca58/cant-remove-failed-virtual-switch-from-hypervs-virtual-switch-manager?forum=winserverhyperv

Answer (score 36):

This worked for me (found [here](http://lkarolak.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/windows-phone-emulator-wasnt-able-to-connect-to-the-windows-phone-operating-system-invalid-pointer/)):

follow the following steps to solve this problem
1.go to network and sharing center
2.go to change adapter setting
3.go to v Ethernet (internal Ethernet port windows phone emulator internal switch)
4.right click it and enable it(if already enabled then disable and enable it again).

Comment: Enabling  vEthernet for windows phone emulator did the trick.

Comment: Worked for me as well! Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but my vEthernet shows no network access. Is this an issue why the emulator won't start? How to fix? The diagnostics report says 
Windows Sockets registry entries required for network connectivity are missing

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. After a long investigation and checking the event log, learned that windows firewall is blocking the emulator connecting to the virtual machine. With that information it is simple to fix the problem.

Yes! Just navigate to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall -> Allow app or feature through Windows Firewall. And click on Add another app button and browse the emulator's path (typically "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\XDE.exe" but may vary based on your installation location). Choose the appropriate network type that you want and add the new item.

Now go back to VS and run your application (close any emulator instance that you have opened already), everything should work fine now!

Answer (score 3):

the solution that worked for me :

1. open Hyper V
2. Select ur VM and go to Virtual Switch Manager.
3. Select Windows Phone Emulator Internal
4. if your connection is Internal then , check the Enable VLAN Identification option
5. press F5 from VS .

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

### Just reboot

No magic needed. Just reboot your development machine after installing Windows Phone SDK.

Answer (score 2):

what your describing is usually due to a Firewall of a third party Anti-virus.

If your using **Symantec** follow this procedure https://stackoverflow.com/a/26326528/4446346

If your using **Windows Firewall** follow this procedure https://stackoverflow.com/a/27685167/4446346

and If you'r using **AVG** do the following procedure:

1. open AVG and go to-->**Options**-->**Firewall Settings**-->**Expert mode**-->**Advanced Settings**.
2. Check the **"Allow any traffic from/to virtual machines supported by firewall**"
3. and click "**OK**".

One more thing you must do is go to the "**Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch**" and uncheck "**AVG network filter driver**"

4. open **Network and Sharing Center**-->**Change Adapter Settings**-->**Properties**
5. Uncheck "**AVG network filter driver**"

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the emulator for the first time, it behaves just like the phone (on first boot) where it will install the initial set of apps and configure them. Which is why the first start will take a long time. You can actually open Hyper-V manager and connect to the VM you had selected at the time of initiating debug - to see the actual progress of what is happening.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It does take a long time, wait for a few minutes before trying the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `Hyper-V` from `Program and Features` and reboot your machine twice. Everything will be default. Enable `Hyper-V` and reboot twice and everything should be working again.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check if your *vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)* in *Network and Sharing Center* is enabled (mine was not, and I got same error like you).

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have enough free space in your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a computer with a touch-screen and get this error, it can be because Hyper-V is trying to port over the touchscreen-fx to the virtual device.

This is (when found) easily corrected:

1. Shut down all attempt at launching virtual devices.
2. Go to: Hyper-V Manager->Hyper-V-settings->Physical GPU:s // Uncheck box "use this GPU with RemoteFX"

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling vmware player 12 if you have ,I have tried several ways but nothing works until I remove it.
Hope it could help you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.