# Cannot Start Windows 10 Device Emulator from Visual Studio - Stuck at Starting OS

Tags: networking, uwp, windows-phone, emulation, hyper-v

I've been trying to use the emulator to test a UWP application from VS2015.  I've got all the latest versions of everything installed.

I've been through all the suggested fixes (apart from installing the updates as I already have newer versions installed) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230855/windows-phone-emulator-8-1-10-stuck-at-loading-the-os).

I've run out of ideas.

I can launch the created emulator from within Hyper-V but I cannot browse the web from this emulator.  The virtual switch that is created is internal so I can only assume this is expected behaviour.

I've repeatedly deleted the VMs and the virtual switches and attempted to start from scratch but nothing seems to work.

I've tried running VS as administrator as well.

When I give in waiting and close the emulator VS reports an error:

> Error     DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during
>   bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device
>   '90F4E8F4-EC5F-4B64-B2E8-6EDE6F813BD3'.':  SystemException - A method
>   was called on an uninitialized object.

**Update**

I've tried disabling Hyper-V and reinstalling this feature but I'm still in the same situation.  I've checked all my BIOS settings relating to Intel HyperThreading and that all seems correct.  I've had other HyperV Linux VMs working fine (now deleted during the attempts to get this working).

I've now gotten to the point where I have a clearer picture of the problem. As I've gotten the following error information.

In Visual Studio the reported error is:

> DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945900

Which also gives the following error from the emulator:

> The emulator is unable to connect to the device operating system: 
>   Couldn't auto-detect the guest system IP address.  Some functionality
>   might be disabled.

When I look at the virtual switch (Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch in Hyper-V) I see the following in the Network and Sharing config:

[image]

I'm assuming this is the root problem.

I've deleted and recreated all the VMs and Virtual Switches many times now.  I've also run every version of `XdeCleanup.exe` on my system, also many times. No matter what I do the virtual switch is incorrectly created without any network access.  I'm assuming that since this has not network access it cannot obtain an IP address which means it's sat in a little world all of it's own.  Poor thing.

Any information on how to get this configured so it does have network access would be really appreciated.

Comment: Goto the Device Manager and delete any hyper-v network adapters, delete the vms, and hyper-v switches and try again http://www.onteorasoftware.com/2016/12/fixing-your-hyper-v-emulators.html

Comment: I just found this exact advice on another SO thread.  Have just completed those steps and about to try again,  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't fixed the issue.  I ran the following commands to view the Hyper-V adapters `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1` and `start devmgmt.msc`, and removed the one adapter.  The recreated config still has the same connectivity issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Phone Emulator not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059248/windows-phone-emulator-not-working)

Comment: @Matt I've thoroughly tried that previous solution long before writing this question.

Comment: Well, ok ... I have a similar issue - it is all about the emulator not starting properly. And I found a couple of links, most of them in SO, but none of them helped yet to solve it. I've retracted the close vote, but suggest to keep the link above. And your question is good, I gave it a +1 already.

Comment: I've been trying on and off for over a year to the point where I have actually given up even trying. I've poured over threads from everywhere and never solved it. So stopped even trying. This question is literally my last attempt. Ever. Hyper-V isn't fit for purpose frankly.